# wxWidgets apps use Raleigh GTK theme instead of selected one

Tags: themes, gtk

wxWidgets apps such as Audacity and Code Blocks are using the Raleigh GTK theme instead of the selected one (Breeze). All other GTK apps are using the selected theme. I am on Kubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two visual aspects:

The first concerns

1 the title bar and window buttons appearance set in *Settings > Window Decorations*. They are common to all applications.

2 the menu bar with *File, Edit, Select, ...* and their dropdowns

3 the window and progress bar that appears when opening or saving an audio file

Items in #2 and #3 do obey your choice of gtk theme **but** you need to have a functional gtk**2** theme. In my *Settings > GNOME/GTK Application Style* I have the default Breeze and Breeze Dark gtk2 themes as well a couple more:

[image: Kubuntu showing gtk2 themes]

Note the little magnifying glass to the right of the listing: it provides a preview of how things would look.

Here's what Audacity looks like with the Numix gtk2 theme:

[image: Audacity with the Numix gtk2 theme]

---

The second visual aspect, which is described in the [Audacity wiki](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/themes.html), is *internally* controlled by your Audacity settings. You can choose from the available options in Audacity's *Edit > Preferences* or even make your own theme.

From [The Audacity wiki](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/themes.html#custom)

[image: Audacity's themes]

Comment: I tried installing a new GTK2 theme and it's now working on both Audacity and CodeBlocks. The breeze theme was probably not working, so it used the second option instead. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your're welcome but I don't understand why the Breeze theme didn't work. It should!